# "No such column on entity" error for an existing custom field

Tags: soql, custom-field

I am trying to run a simple SOQL on a custom object:

```
SELECT Id, Course_Link__c
FROM Course__c
```

But instead I am getting an error saying:

> SELECT Id, Course_Link__c
>              ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:12 No such column 'Course_Link__c' on entity 'Course__c'...

I checked this field in the Setup section for this object and surprisingly see it there. I event copy-pasted the API name of the field and re-run the query, but still saw no effect.
[image: setup section for Course__c]

When I checked this fields in the Developer Console (Ctrl + Shift + O > Look Up Course.obj), I found that Course_Link__c was missing:

[image: developer console]

Does anybody know why the Course_Link__c field is not recognized by Developer Console? In general, why Salesforce exposes such strange behavior?

Comment: Click the field name, then "Field Accessibility". Is the field available for your profile?

Comment: Can you check the FLS has been given and secondly are you executing same DE from Developer console?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that this field is actually visible to your user via `Field Level Security`.

1. Click the field name in your Setup UI to view the field definition detail.
2. On this detail view, there will be a <kbd>Set Field-Level Security</kbd> button.
3. Make sure **Visible** is selected for your Profile.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually if the system administrator profile does not have access to Read access to the fields .

I would recommend checking the Field Level Security for the System Administrator Profile for the field Course_Link__c